# Sql server finding the number of occurence of a string

Tags: sql-server

How to find the number of occurences in a sentence using sql server/Tsql?

In the following string value, I want to find the number of words that appear more than once:

"My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain."

in the above sentence 'every' and 'several' appear twice, how do i extract these words without hard code

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail as to what you are trying to achieve here, because your question is currently very ambiguous.  It would also help to see some example data, your desired output and the attempts you have made so far.

Comment: suppose if im having a sentence 
"My conscience hath a thousand several tongues,

And every tongue brings in a several tale,

And every tale condemns me for a villain."         in this example every and several repeated several times how do i extract this words without hard code

Comment: figure out a way to split the sentence by spaces (lots of ways), then use count() with group by.  you'll probably need to remove  punctuation marks as well

Comment: although it's definitely possible using the functions available, have to ask if a relational database is the best place to be doing such operations?

Comment: `four lines of sentence` please define sentence, and is that four sentences in one `varchar` or four separate rows. `the number of repeated words` define word: what about punctuation, numbers any other characters? You are going to have to be much, mcuh clearer about what data you have and what you are trying to do with it, please [edit] your question and elaborate

Comment: Sql server is such an expensive place to do this task imo. Why not use hadoop?

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way to get you started, though be aware that this is *far* from a complete solution, as you will need to define what constitutes a word.  This seems simple but is actually very difficult.

For example, in my script and output below, you can see that `words,` is considered a word due to splitting on a space character.

So just get rid of punctutation!  Easy, right?  Well, how would you make sure to get rid of a single quote at the start and end of a word such as `a sentence where a 'word' is quoted` but ignore the single quote within a contraction such as `don't replace this one`?

You will need to do a *lot* of preprocessing or accept that you will get a lot of incorrect outputs with whatever you are trying to achieve here.

---

#### Query

```
declare @t table(txt varchar(500));
insert into @t values
 ('My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain.')
,('Another test string with no repeated words so that there are more values to show how this could work on an entire dataset')
,('And another that does repeat words, so that those words, where they match can be aggregated')
;

select t.txt
      ,s.[value] as word
      ,count(s.[value]) as occurances
from @t as t
    cross apply string_split(t.txt,' ') as s
group by t.txt
        ,s.[value]
having count(s.[value]) > 1;
```

#### Output

| txt | word | occurances |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain. | a | 3 |
| My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain. | And | 2 |
| My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain. | every | 2 |
| My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain. | several | 2 |
| And another that does repeat words, so that those words, where they match can be aggregated | that | 2 |
| And another that does repeat words, so that those words, where they match can be aggregated | words, | 2 |

Comment: is it possible without string_split function?

Comment: You will need *some* kind of string split function, either the built in version or, if not available, one you have added to the database yourself.  There are numerous examples of how to do this online.

Answer (score 0):

There are way too many "what if's" to write something that exactly meets all your possible requirents, however the following should give you an idea to work with:

```
select [value]
from String_Split('My conscience hath a thousand several tongues, And every tongue brings in a several tale, And every tale condemns me for a villain',' ')
group by value having count(*)>1


value
--------
a
And
every
several
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question before so I am modifying my answer.
Create store routine first that will accept string as a param.

```
DELIMITER //
create function `find_occurances`(string varchar(192))
returns varchar(192) deterministic
begin
    declare substr varchar(191) default "";
    declare occurances int default 0;
    declare length int default 0;
    declare temp_str varchar(191) default string;
    DELETE FROM occurances_in_sentence;
    create temporary table if not exists occurances_in_sentence(value varchar(51),occurances int);
    set length = round((length(string) - length(Replace(string," ","")))/1);
    while length >= 0 do
        set substr = SUBSTRING_INDEX(string," ",1);
        if(length(substr) = 0)then 
            return substr;
        end if;
        set occurances=round((length(string) - length(Replace(string,substr,"")))/length(substr));
        insert into occurances_in_sentence values (substr,occurances);
        set string = Replace(string,substr,"");
        set string = trim(string);
        set length = length -1;
    end while;
    return 1;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

After successfully creating function. Call your function with the string.

```
select find_occurances("This is testing of every occurance in sentence of every number") as sub;
```

What it does that it creates a temporary table of your result.

```
select * from occurances_in_sentence;
```

[image: Result of above sentence]

Comment: Does this not require you to both know what you are looking for and to hard code it in advance? That's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: I have changed answer and now you can even run it.

Comment: Using a `while` loop for this will have terrible performance compared to set-based approaches.